# How does the sum of an infinite series calculated?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For example, let's take the following power series, where $-1 \lt x \lt 1.$

$$s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n = \frac{x}{(1 - x)^2}. $$

But if we'll expand $s(x)$, we'll get:

$$s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n =  1x^1 + 2x^2 + 3x^3 +  \dots+ nx^n + \dots$$

In other words , we summing an infinite amount of numbers, how does it converge to finite number?

To clarify my question, I'm asking how the sum determined, not how to calculate it.

Comment: Well if you believe that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^n}=1/(1-x)$, you could just take the derivative of both sides and multiply by $x$.

Comment: If you're talking about *power series* then you *should have studied already series or number series, where convergence is defined and explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$ defined as $\lim_{t \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^t nx^n$. This is determined as any [limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 1):

Never think of the notation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ as summing an infinite number of numbers. Always think of it as a limit.

Try starting with a simpler example. Are you happy with the fact that $$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}  + \frac{1}{8} + \dots = 2?$$